# How build Get with two parameters in Web API

Tags: asp.net, c, asp.net-web-api

I'm very confused on how to configure a Get with more than one in SQL.
the answers in the forum are very fragmented and so far I have not been able to implement a solution to the code below. I know it should not be too complicated, but I can not.
My code is the one below.
Thank you very much.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("cliente/{paramOne}/{paramTwo}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetNomeNasc(string paramOne, string paramTwo)
{
    try
    {
        Cliente cliente = null;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "select id, nome, datanascimento, nascidoEm, email from clientes where nome =" + @paramOne + " and nascidoEm = " + @paramTwo;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramOne, paramTwo);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    cliente = new Cliente()
                    {
                        Id = reader["id"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                        Nome = reader["nome"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["nome"].ToString(),
                        NascidoEm = reader["nascidoEm"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["nascidoEm"].ToString(),
                        DataNascimento = reader["datanascimento"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["datanascimento"]),
                        Email = reader["email"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["email"].ToString()
                    };
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, cliente);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the underlying Database Driver you can use either named or anonymous Parameters.

Your problem ist that you are not adding individual `Parameters.AddwithValue(string name, Object object)` expect a Parameter name and the value that is to be inserted. Look at the [definition of this function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

An even better way of doing that would be the following:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@paramOne", DbType, size).Value = paramOne
```

which you would have to adapt according to what is allowed for the individual column which the value should be added to. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx).

For Example we want to insert into a column which expects an integer, you would have the following line

```
command.Parameters.Add("@paramOne", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = paramOne
```

**Be aware** that like this you have to add the Parameters individually. Depending on the Db Driver you have to do that in the order they are referenced in (Anonymous) or can be referenced by name and the order is of no concern.

You can also use the [Parameters.AddRange()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx) Function to either add an Array of values or pre-constructed SqlParameters.